# Access Linux after installing another OS

Tags: boot

I recently installed Fedora 20 and during the installations, I made a new disk partition where I installed Windows after Fedora. I do not get the alternative of booting Fedora now. How would I go about booting Fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **EasyBCD** to dual-boot your OSs. It's simple and there are many documents for this...

Download it from: http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/ or search the web...

Comment: Any free alternatives? (I am currently googling for this, but I ask for several alternatives.) EDIT: Nevermind, I need to learn to look closer.

Comment: It has free edition too... Look carefully! Or download free edition from here: http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

Comment: What is the advantage of that EasyBCD thingy over all the many free alternatives available on pretty much every live CD?

Comment: OMG! EasyBCD has free edition too!!!! and it's more simple for new users than other softwares (I think)... Otherwise he can use `grub-install` command to install grub on /boot partition and after than edit `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file...

Comment: Freeware is not free software! But that's the old free beer vs. freedom story.

Comment: I succeeded using EasyBCD and GRUB2.

Comment: Congratulation :)

Answer (score 0):

You first installed Fedora in one partition, afterwards you installed Windows on another partition. This did not only install windows inside that partition, but also replaced the old boot loader by a windows boot loader, which does not give you the option to boot your Fedora anymore.

The next time you install such a system, first install Windows and then your Linux distribution. Linux distributions usually recognize Windows without problems and add a boot option for it.

For now you need some kind of Linux live CD to get a boot loader able to boot your system. How did you install your Fedora? You probably still have the installation media around. This should allow you to reinstall a good boot loader and repair your system that way.

[Here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html#s2-rescuemode-boot-reinstall-bootloader) is the official documentation for Fedora 14, I couldn't find the one for Fedora 20, but there are good chances it works the same way.

Comment: I did install Fedora by USB, but did format the USB to make a Win7-USB. So, what you are saying is that I should remake the Fedora USB so that I am able to repair the system from Fedora Live?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need a way to boot your system into Fedora rescue mode. That Fedora USB should be just the right thing.

Comment: Ok, I have successfully created the Fedora USB. I assume I want to do the following (http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/s1-rescuemode-boot.html) (17.2.1). However, I do not understand where I am supposed to write linux rescue, seeing as I do not see an installation prompt as described in the guide.